# How to synchronize local directory with another local directory on another partition or disk

Tags: windows, ftp, synchronization, directory, winscp

I would like to **synchronize my local directory content with another local directory on another partition or disk** (or e.g. a pendrive).
I can synchronize my local directory content with a remote one (through FTP) with [WinSCP](http://winscp.net), even with keeping remote directory up to date continously, but I don't know any programs that do the same between local directories.
I'm mainly looking for a program **for Windows**, and *it should also be compatible with XP*.

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ROBOCOPY a command line utility can do that (and more). It is included with Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. Available in the Windows Resource Kit for various other versions (Windows 2000, Windows 2003 etc).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but could you be a bit more specific? How would you synchronize or keep a directory up to date continously with robocopy?
AND I didn't mention, but I would like to use the program on Windows XP... :( I will complement the original post.

Comment: btw someone writes that Robocopy cannot do things like what I asked: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/using-robocopy-xp010-sync-files-t2532791.html#post8243432 ...

Comment: SyncToy might be more what your after then. [SyncToy 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155)

Comment: Yes, HerrStrinson has already recommended it, but unfortunately it can't keep a directory up-to-date after modifying any files in it like WinSCP. :(

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at Microsofts [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) 
It provides a intuitive gui in case your not much of a fan of the shell. It has about the same features as robocopy, though - I'm not sure which requirement of yours is not met... it does 2way sync on file level, latest timestamp wins.

Comment: yes, in the meantime I have also found this program, which seems to be really useful. You can set a "left" and a "right" directory which can be synchronized, but I chose the "Echo" option, which performs the following task, citing: "New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames and deletes on the left are repeated on the right." That's exactly what I needed. Thanks, I'm just testing this program, if it's OK, your answer will be accepted. ;)

Comment: hmm, there's a function that I'm missing: no option for keeping a directory up-to-date, like with WinSCP (which listens for changes on given directories, and updates remote directories immediately if any changes happen). Or maybe there was an option that escaped my attention... :S

Answer (score 1):

Is [Unison](http://freshmeat.net/projects/unison) what you want?

> Unison is a file-synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows
>   two copies of a collection of files and directories to be stored on
>   different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified
>   separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in
>   each replica to the other. Unison can deal with updates to both
>   replicas of a distributed directory structure. Updates that do not
>   conflict are propagated automatically. Conflicting updates are
>   detected and displayed. Unison can communicate through a direct socket
>   link or through an rsh/ssh tunnel. It uses network bandwidth
>   efficiently.

([Download page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download.html))

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try too! What I don't like about it now is that installation is not too simple, because it has to be built, citing from readme: "We provide two options for building Unison on MS Windows.  Both options require the Cygwin layer to be able to use a few GNU tools as well as the OCaml distribution version.  The options differ in the C compiler employed: MS Visual C++ (MSVC) vs Cygwin GNU C." But it doesn't mean it's not a good program, so I'll give it a go. Here are some screenshots if someone is interested: http://ostatic.com/unison/screenshot/

Comment: @Sk8erPeter There are [windows binaries](http://alan.petitepomme.net/unison/index.html) available.

Comment: sorry for not giving a feedback for a long time, but I didn't have time to try the program's options until now. It's a great program, BUT I still miss the opportunity to keep my directories up-to-date like in WinSCP, which can continously monitor my files in a given directory, and "upgrade" my local OR remote files when there are any changes. I would really like to have a WinSCP-alternative for local files... :( But thanks for your recommendation, you got a vote-up!

Comment: @Sk8erPeter oh WinsSCP has a feature where it triggers sync when file has changed? Didn't know that - thought you have to initiate command by hand. Unison does that by hand except you can set up a cron job/schedule task so it does it for you each x minutes.